# EC2 Container Service Networking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

My team is exploring different toolsets (Docker Datacenter, DC/OS, etc.) for a CaaS Platform offering. We're currently looking at Amazon EC2 Container Service (ECS) as a possible solution, but are having trouble translating our docker-compose files into ECS tasks.

Specifically, we're not sure how to approach networking within a task in ECS. I was under the impression that a task was sort of analogous to a compose, but it seems to handle networking in a very different way.

E.g. the https://github.com/docker/example-voting-app expects two networks, 'front-tier' and 'back-tier' each of which seems to be stock overlay networks. How does one create these in ECS?

Answer (score 0):

ECS supports docker compose style container deployment using 
cmd-ecs-cli-compose.

Please refer to the following documenation
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html

The example you have shared uses docker networking, which was added to docker in 1.9.
Amazon ECS still does not support docker networking options when defining tasks, so you will not get the example to work as is.

Of course you can redefine the task and use legacy docker link features to open access between containers.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the reply! Supposedly "only Docker compose version 1 syntax is supported" which suggests to me that everything would need to be on the same, default network (as opposed to setting up separate ones as in the github example).

Comment: Yes, Docker compose 1 does not support the networking features introduced 1.9

Comment: You will need to add links between the containers

Comment: The "default network" is not how docker-compose v 1 worked... overlay networks didn't exist yet.  You had to manually add links in between containers that needed to speak to one another, and couldn't do circular links.